# How to Use a Date Range with Allen Brown's "ConcatRelated"

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am using [ConcatRelated](http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html) over a date range but can't get it to work. I can use a single date like `a_Date=Date()-1` with no problems. However, if I try to substitute `Date` with `Between` and take the dates from a form or even directly, it doesn't work.

Below is an example of my SQL query:

```
SELECT y.A_date, SUM(y.Absent) AS SumOfAbsent, SUM(y.Tardy) AS SumOfTardy, SUM(y.Vacation) AS SumOfVacation, ConcatRelated(
            'Reason',
            'Absent_Tardy_Vac',
            'A_date=Date()-1',
            'Reason',
            ',  '
        ) AS ConCat_Reasons
FROM Absent_Tardy_Vac AS y
WHERE y.A_date = Date()-1
GROUP BY y.A_date;
```

That query works great. But when I try to use a date range:

```
SELECT y.A_date, Sum(y.Absent) AS RSumOfAbsent, Sum(y.Tardy) AS RSumOfTardy, Sum(y.Vacation) AS RSumOfVacation, ConcatRelated(
'Reason',
'Absent_Tardy_Vac',
'A_date= Between [Forms]![Date Prompt]![txtBDate] And [Forms]![Date Prompt]![txtEDate]',
'Reason',
',  '
) AS RConCat_Reasons
FROM Absent_Tardy_Vac AS y
WHERE (((y.A_date) Between [Forms]![Date Prompt]![txtBDate] And [Forms]![Date Prompt]![txtEDate]))
GROUP BY y.A_date;
```

I get an Error which is

> Error 3075: Syntax error(missing operator) in expression.  *'A_date
>   IS Between [Forms]![Date Prompt]![txtBDate] And [Forms]![Date
>   Prompt]![txtEDate]'*

This works in all my other queries where I am not using ConcatRelated.  `txtBDate` and `txtEDate` are fields in a form I'm using to pass the beginning and end dates to multiple queries that run for one report.

Comment: Do not include an equal sign here: `A_date Between one_thing And another_thing`

Comment: I had already tried that and I get an error 3061: Too few parameters. Expected 2.

Answer (score 1):

The db engine can resolve the references to those text boxes in the main query's `WHERE` clause.  However those same references in the `ConcatRelated` expression are not resolved and Access interprets them to be parameters.

The solution is to include the values of those text boxes, instead of the text box names, in your `ConcatRelated` *strWhere* argument (the third argument).

```sql
ConcatRelated(
    'Reason',
    'Absent_Tardy_Vac',
    'A_date Between '
        & Format([Forms]![Date Prompt]![txtBDate], '\#yyyy-m-d\#')
        & ' And '
        & Format([Forms]![Date Prompt]![txtEDate], '\#yyyy-m-d\#'),
    'Reason',
    ', '
    ) AS RConCat_Reasons
```